Find with -mtime fails checking current day files
Consider the two commands below which are scheduled to run at the same time (Via Autosys, at exactly 8 AM).
The find command removed files older than 15 days but exited with non-zero status with:
???find missing /app/source/a.txt no such file or directory

However, a.txt is one day old. Why is the find command validating a recent file which was present during its run but moved to another folder at the same time?
find /app/source -type f -name -mtime +15 rm -f {} \;

mv /app/source/a.txt /app/backup/


isn't there a " -exec " before rm ?

A directory is basically a list of filenames. 
When you run find and specify test(s)
that look at file attributes/properties (rather than just filename),
find must query the filesystem for the attributes/properties
of each file listed in each directory. 
Thus, find has no way of knowing that a.txt is a recent file
other than by calling stat("a.txt").
As you probably understand, your mv command moved the file
between when find read the directory and when it called stat().

To avoid this, we need to alter the scheduling to diffferent interval? BACKUP should at 8 AM and Purge at 08:05 AM ?

If you want them to run as close as possible to the same time, the simplest approach would be to put the two commands into a script file (separated by ; or a newline) and run that (e.g., at 8:00 AM), so the second command runs immediately after the first one finishes.

This is what is known as a race condition. The only way for find to know that this is a new file that shouldn't be deleted is by looking at the file. So find first finds the file, then checks its date.
I  your case, it seems that your other command deleted the file after find saw that it was present in the directory, but before it had time to check it for its age. Hence the error.

So find command takes a snap of all available list when issued with -mtime and check one by one ?

@VeeraV not a snap, as such. It's like G-man explained in their answer: there is a tiny bit of time between the moment find identifies a file and the moment it runs stat() on it to see the file's age and your file was moved in that tiny bit of time.

thanks to both for clarifying
